# Optimizing pow algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I have to raise a number to the power of 1/2.2 which is 0.45454545... many times. Actually I have to do this in a loop. Simple pow/powf is very slow (when I comment out this pow from my loop code it's a loot faster). Is there any way to optimize such operation?

Comment: The answer depends on the value range of your argument numbers. If you only have a limited number of different arguments, a lookup table might be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give a look at: [Optimized Approximative pow() in C / C++](http://martin.ankerl.com/2012/01/25/optimized-approximative-pow-in-c-and-cpp/)

It also includes a benchmark.